# Ideal algorithmic approach -- Rule-engine / Decision-Tree and some Learning logic?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification, rule-engine, bayesian, inference

My requirement is probably close to what one expects of an "Expert System". And looking for the simplest solution, that can give me real-time or near-real time inference, with some offline (non-realtime) learning capabilities.

To elaborate, my problem is --

Watch a log that is being updated live, and classify each entry as Red, Green and Blue.
The classification into Red, Green, Blue is based on logic codified as production-rules (as I imagine it today).

The point where it gets challenging is --

1) Log entries tagged Blue will eventually have to be tagged red / green, based on subsequent log entries, where we hope to have more detailed information, so there is a bit of remembering to be done. The exact duration to wait, isn't known in advance, but there's a max limit. Of course, at any given point in time, there could be several hundred-thousand entries that are tagged Blue.

2) The rules that determine Red & Green are not perfect, so sometimes mistakes happen with labeling. So an occasional manual audit reveals these mistakes. My main challenge is to see if I could automate some part of rule-updating, with minimal programming effort.

My (continuing study) reveals that RETE algorithm based rule-engine might serve my classification & labeling, including the re-labelling. If that works, I still need to figure how to automate the part of "learning from mistakes" ? Can one take a statistical approach -- s.a. Bayesian classification ? Also, could one take the Bayesian classification completely as against Rules-Engine, for the initial classification s.t. I've manually trained the system sufficiently ? Bayesian approach seems to "dumb down" the task of maintaining a correct set of rules, by "trust the statistics" approach, especially as there are these periodic manual audits.

PS> My main application is written in C++ (if that matters).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like **Complex Event Processing** (CEP), where you have rules and the ability to use time calculations like *event X is within 2 minutes after event y*.

In *Java* land, [Drools Fusion](http://www.jboss.org/drools/documentation) (or Drools Expert) would handle that really well (I am biased though). In *C++* land... well maybe you can set up a `drools-camel-server` and communicate through XML with it.

Comment: Thanks @geoffrey-de-smet. Had come accross CEP sometime back (esply ESPER), but somehow lost that track, nice of you to bring it up. Trying to catchup on Drools Fusion, I came accross this [interesting post](http://hansgilde.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/drools-fusion-oss-competitor-to-businessevents/) and a more interesting comment, which compares ESPER with Drools-Fusion. The ways in which both might complement each other is what would be interesting to figure out. This is certainly a path I want to explore deeper. Thanks again.